# What do brackets mean around column names in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I added a field in SQL Server 2008 and it put the column name in brackets like this: `[column2]`. The other column names don't have brackets. What do the brackets mean?

The column is named `macro-writer`

Should I remove the minus sign and replace it with an underscore?

Comment: OP said `should i remove the minus sign and replace with underscore`.  I would, if only so I don't have to use `[` and `]` everywhere!

Comment: It'll try to perform an arithmetic operation of `macro-writer` and will throw invalid column name exceptions for `macro` and `writer`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Columns enclosed in square brackets are usually keywords or contain special characters or spaces.

What specific column name do you have enclosed in brackets?

Comment: [macro-writer] [macro-writer]

Comment: A hyphen is considered a special character.

Comment: Yes, if the column name is INDEX then we need to use the [] to take out result. As INDEX is keyword

Answer (score 36):

Brackets are a form of quoting.  It's only necessary if the column name contains spaces or punctuation or conflicts with a reserved word, but many wizards will just add the brackets for all field names to avoid the logic for deciding whether they are necessary.

Answer (score 9):

Brackets allow you to use characters and names which are not allowed like spaces, reserved words and names starting with numbers

**invalid** my column, 1column col%umn, table

**valid** [my column], [1column], [col%umn], [table]

of course now you can become really creative  :-)

```
create table [table]([table] varchar(20))

insert [table] values ('table')

select [table] from [table]
```

Comment: you will never have a table that has a mix of hebrew and thai font

Comment: Well, why not try it and see for yourself ;). Works on SQL 2005, 2008
create table [แสดงבוקרǣ]
(
 ID int not null
)

Comment: Select [table] from [table] where [table].[table] = 'table'. I love it!!

Comment: I think that using such spaces and special characters for a column identifier could just be making unnecessary trouble for onesself elsewhere and generally avoid it.   But what is the advantage of using `[my column]` over the more traditional SQL `"my column"`?

Answer (score 4):

See related questions with answers:

- [[] brackets in sql statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153861/brackets-in-sql-statements/154416#154416)
- [Do different databases use different name quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214309/do-different-databases-use-different-name-quote/214344#214344)
- [What is the difference between single and double quotes in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql/1992403#1992403)

I would recommend using underscore instead of dash in identifier names.

Answer (score 3):

Brackets allow you to delimit names in SQL Server. This allows you to do such things as use keywords [count] or include spaces [my column name].

**EDIT**: For your follow up question, if this is a new column and there's no risk of breaking existing code, then I'd at least recommend replacing the hyphen with an underscore. Our own internal naming standards are to use PascalCase (e.g., MacroWriter) rather than underscores.