# Syntax error missing operator on inner join

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have made the following query :

```
SELECT [tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE.Verantwrd], [tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE.WBS_Id], [tbl_Imp_tabel        WBS WPE.Koptekst], [tbl_Users.UserName], [tbl_Users.WPENaam]
FROM  [tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE]
INNER JOIN [tbl_Users]
ON tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE.Verantwrd = tbl_Users.WPENaam ;
```

Howver, my access tells me that i have a missing operator on the line :

```
ON tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE.Verantwrd = tbl_Users.WPENaam ;
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten square brackets around table name **[tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE.Verantwrd]** in ON clause. [**Usage of [ ] in SQL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153861/brackets-in-sql-statements)

```
SELECT [tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE.Verantwrd], [tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE.WBS_Id], [tbl_Imp_tabel        WBS WPE.Koptekst], [tbl_Users.UserName], [tbl_Users.WPENaam]
FROM  [tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE]
INNER JOIN [tbl_Users]
ON [tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE.Verantwrd] = tbl_Users.WPENaam ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have **missed square barckets** around table name in **ON** clause

Try this

```
SELECT [tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE].[Verantwrd], [tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE].[WBS_Id], [tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE].[Koptekst], [tbl_Users.UserName], [tbl_Users.WPENaam]
FROM  [tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE]
INNER JOIN [tbl_Users]
ON [tbl_Imp_tabel WBS WPE].[Verantwrd] = tbl_Users.WPENaam ;
```