# Explanation of SQL table syntax for Microsoft Access DB

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to make a Microsoft Access database that is connected to a view/form for a home project. To display the data on the form, I intend to query with inline SQL.

I have found examples online, but no real explanation, so I hope someone can explain the following:

**1. What is the difference between these two**

```
table.Countries.[CountryName]

table.Countries.CountryName
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: 1. no difference.   2. * is wildcard.

Comment: That asteric is a wildcard, meaning it will be pull all records where the field `CountryName` is essentially not blank.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[\] brackets in sql statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153861/brackets-in-sql-statements) Also VBA is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets qualify the text within as a column name. They are required if someone, against recommendation, creates a column name the same as a reserved word. For example, if you have a column named `Date`, the following will error:

```
SELECT t.Date FROM Table1 t
```

In this case, you would need to qualify the column name with square brackets:

```
SELECT t.[Date] FROM Table1 t
```

It is HIGHLY recommended to just avoid using reserved words as column names. Additionally, if you want to alias a column name with spaces in the alias, square brackets are required:

```
SELECT t.MyDate AS [Invoice Date] FROM Table1 t
```

The `*` is the MS Access wildcard for the LIKE clause. It's worth noting that Microsoft SQL Server uses the `%` as the wildcard.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation.