# MySQL Syntax Error "right syntax to use near 'desc"

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I'm working in Python and using the MySQLdb module. I have a working connection (I can run other queries successfully)

```
c.execute("ALTER TABLE results ADD COLUMN desc TEXT")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35,
    in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
right syntax to use near 'desc TEXT' at line 1")
```

I've had similar trouble before; MySQLdb's syntax error messages are *terribly* non-descriptive.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Step 1.  Compare your syntax against this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html.  The error message is not supposed to be descriptive.

Comment: I *think* the error message comes from the SQL engine itself, not MySQLdb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `desc` is reserved.  It is used in an `ORDER BY` clause

You may be able to get away with using it if you put back-ticks around it, but I think you would be better off changing the name to a non-reserved word.

Comment: This is it. `desc` is the mysql keyword for descending order.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Second time I read it, desc hmmmm.

Answer (score 0):

`desc` is a reserved keyword in MySQL - documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

If you insist on using `desc` you should escape it using the back tick character (`) - as described here: [How do I escape reserved words used as column names? MySQL/Create Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)

I'll recommend you to change the `desc` column name to e.g. `description`, as I believe it is best practice never to include reserved keywords in the db schema.