# MySQL query multiple table inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL query but it seems to be getting an error while I try to run it. Since I'm a newbie I'd like some advice of what I should do to correct it. I just want to show the name, quantity and order date of the orders that has 1 or more pending products. Thanks a lot!

```
select product.name, order_details.quantity, order.date from product,order_details,order 
inner join order on order_details.order_id=order.id 
inner join product on order_details.product_id=product.id 
inner join customer on order.cust_id=costumer.id WHERE order.pending=>1
```

Comment: which error you are getting..??

Comment: If the pending information is in the order table, how do you know which products are still pending ?

Comment: You are right, I get no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a table called **order**.  This word has special significance in SQL.  Your options are to rename the table, or quote it whenever you want to query from it.

Easiest solution is to change.

```
inner join order ....
```

to

```
inner join `order`
```

Be sure to use back-quotes around the table name.

Answer (score 0):

You have a table named 'order', which is a reserved word in SQL.

One solution is to prefix the table name with the database name as explained in [Craic Computing blog](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/tables-named-with-reserved-words-in.html)
Another one is to wrap the table name with the ` character as you can read [in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
SELECT product.name, order_details.quantity, `order`.date
FROM product
INNER JOIN order_details ON product.id = order_detail.product_id
INNER JOIN `order` ON `order`.id = order_detail.order_id
WHERE `order`.pending >= 1
```

As said in other answers, `order`is a reserved keyword in SQL, surround it with backquotes.

Maybe you should store the `pending` information in the `order_detail` table (1 if pending, 0 if not), in order to keep track of which product is still pending instead of incrementing/decrementing the `order.pending` field.

In this case, you could make the following query :

```
SELECT product.name, order_details.quantity, `order`.date
FROM product
INNER JOIN order_details ON product.id = order_detail.product_id
INNER JOIN `order` ON `order`.id = order_detail.order_id
WHERE `order_detail`.pending = 1
```

Which would return all the products still pending in your orders instead of every product from orders in which maybe only one is pending.

Comment: You are right with your comment above. I get no results.. What should I do, any suggestions? I'm a total newbie.

Comment: I edited my answer to try to answer your question. Hope this helps.