# SELECT * FROM Linked MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, linked-server, ssms-2012

I have a SQL Server 2012.(120.120.55.15)

Today I linked MySQL server(120.120.55.30) to my SQLServer and gave it a name **"MYSQL".**

In Object Explorer everything seems fine. I can see **MySQL** server's database "**exampleDataBase**" and tables in it.

But when I try to run select query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   openquery
        (
        MYSQL, 
        '
         SELECT * 
         FROM [exampleDataBase].[msProcMatrix]
        '
        )
```

I get a mistake:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for
>   linked server "MYSQL" reported an error. The provider did not give any
>   information about the error. Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for
>   linked server "MYSQL".

What should be additionally done to use my linked MySQL server?

Comment: You have to adjust if SQL Server Management Studio uses 64Bit so for MySQL Connector ODBC it must be 64bit too

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the decision:

```
SELECT * 
FROM openquery(MYSQL, 'SELECT * FROM exampleDataBase.msProcMatrix')
```

Without brackets!

Strange for me but works...

Comment: It's the proper way to escape column names in MySQL (NOT MSSQL!)

See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2889884/244067

Comment: and the column names are case sensitive I found too!

Answer (score 4):

This worked great for me after fighting the same issue on MS SQL Server 2008 64bit using the MY SQL 3.51 64 bit ODBC driver

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY
(
   linked_server_name,
   'SELECT * FROM linked_database_name.linked_table_name'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need a schema name between the database name and the table name.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   openquery
        (
        MYSQL, 
        '
         SELECT * 
         FROM [exampleDataBase].**[dbo]**.[msProcMatrix]
        '
        )
```

Comment: Mariau, find my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

When I working with linked server, I never use `Select * From`.

Try with `Select Column1, Column2, ... ColumnN From`.

Always works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the default catalog ("exampleDataBase") is configured in ODBC, the following will work as well:

select * from MYSQL...msProcMatrix

Answer (score -2):

You Can try this query .

EXEC 
(
'SELECT * FROM [exampleDataBase].[msProcMatrix]'
) 
AT MYSQL

Answer (score -2):

Please try the statement in the format below .. 
for me it works very well

```
SELECT * 
FROM   openquery
        (
        MYSQL, 
        '
         SELECT * 
         FROM [MYSQL]...[exampleDataBase].[msProcMatrix]
        '
        )
```

Including the extra levels in the name may solve your issue.