# mysql won't order by INT

Tags: mysql

I have set up a table with a column called order. I made sure it is set as INT. I can't seem to get the results to list in order. I currently have 5 rows with numbers 1-5 in a random order in those rows. However, I can't get those rows to go in order. Maybe I am doing this completely wrong, as I am new to MySql. Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM faq ORDER BY 'order'
```

Comment: see this post it explains why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table

Comment: Don't use reserved words for entity names, in first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the back-tick, not the quote:

```
SELECT * FROM faq ORDER BY `order`
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use backticks in mysql, not quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM faq ORDER BY `order`
```

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
SELECT * FROM faq ORDER BY `order`
```

You're using single-quotes in your example.  MySQL uses backticks for wrapping table names, field names, etc.  You need to use backticks in this case because `order` is a reserved word in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You're quoting `'order'` like a string, so the sorting will be done by the value `order` itself (a string) rather than by the column. Change them to backticks instead.

Comment: Dropping them completely here isn't an option since `order` is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

You should use backtik not quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM faq ORDER BY `order`;
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html