# Grouping values from mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli, group-by

I'm in the process of putting together a PHP/mySQL form with only basic knowledge of both. For the first drop-down list on the form, I'd like to pull the options from a mySQL database. I've set this up as follows:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM test";
$result = mysqli_query($link , $query);
?>
Select your group number:
<select name="group">
<?php
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['group'];?>"><?php echo $line['group'];?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

However, this returns each group value even when they're identical, so I end up with duplicates (FIGURE 1). I'd like to group all like values (FIGURE 2).

[image]

I understand using GROUP BY might accomplish this, but when I include GROUP BY in my code as follows, my drop-down just ends up empty.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test GROUP BY group";
```

Am I making a mistake with my use of GROUP BY?

**NOTE:** "group" is the id of the column I'm fetching.

Comment: 1000th question today on mysql reserved words...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group is not a good name for a field because it is a reserved word in mysql.

You can do it but your query needs to look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test GROUP BY `group`";
```

Please read this:
[How do I escape reserved words used as column names? MySQL/Create Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)

and this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Very helpful - corrected the field name and works perfectly. Thanks for the explanation and links!