# You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"`insert into hall_booking(name,address,event_type,hallNo,arrival_time,arrival_da' at line 1`

When running this query:

```
insert into hall_booking (
    name,address,event_type,hallNo,arrival_time,arrival_date,dep_time,dep_date,identity,emailid,contact,total_members,desc,catering,service,decoration,other
) values (
   '$nm','$add','$typ','$roomno','$arrv','$arrivaldate','$departure','$dDate','$idt','$emailid','$cont','$desc','200','200','200','200')
```

Again a problem occured in sql statement. What mistake i did?

Comment: Are you doing this on the MySQL command line? Also, have you verified your schema?

Comment: `desc` and `identity` are keywords in sql so put them in `''` (quotes) or user some other column names

Comment: You appear to be open to [SQL Injection](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-injection?sort=votes&pageSize=15).  If you don't want your database to get owned, you need to use parameterized queries for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You look as if you're using protected keywords as column names (you shouldn't really do this).

Try escaping them with `

```
insert into hall_booking (
name,address,event_type,hallNo,arrival_time,
arrival_date,dep_time,dep_date,`identity`,
emailid,contact,total_members,`desc`,catering,service,decoration,other) 
values(
'$nm','$add','$typ','$roomno','$arrv',
'$arrivaldate','$departure','$dDate','$idt',
'$emailid','$cont','$desc','200','200','200','200')
```

Comment: Make sure you accept the answer that gave your solution. Points make the world go round :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:
insert into hall_booking (name,address,event_type,hallNo,arrival_time,arrival_date,dep_time,dep_date,identity,emailid,contact,total_members,desc,catering,service,decoration,other)
values ( '".$nm."','".$add."','".$typ."','".$roomno."','".$arrv."','".$arrivaldate."','".$departure."','".$dDate."','".$idt."','".$emailid."','".$cont."','".$desc."','200','200','200','200')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are using a reserved keyword `desc` as a column name. To overcome this error you can replace your query with the following one:

```
insert into hall_booking (name,address,event_type,hallNo,arrival_time,arrival_date,dep_time,dep_date,`identity`,emailid,contact,total_members,`desc`,catering,service,decoration,other) values ('$nm','$add','$typ','$roomno','$arrv','$arrivaldate','$departure','$dDate','$idt','$emailid','$cont','$desc','200','200','200','200')"
```

Also you can refer this article for more clarification:

[How do I escape reserved words used as column names? MySQL/Create Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)

Comment: mysql uses backticks, not double quotes unless certain flags are turned on (not the default), to delimit reserved words

Comment: Oh really!! You can use double quotes if ANSI SQL mode is enabled! See the post whose link I posted. And I have been doing that for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not mentioned last value

```
   "INSERT INTO `hall_booking`(`name`,`address  ,`event_type`,`hallNo`,`arrival_time`,`arrival_date`,`dep_time`,`dep_date`,`IDENTITY`,`emailid`,`contact`,`total_members`,`DESC`,`catering`,`service`,`decoration`,`other`)
    VALUES('".$nm."',
           '".$add."',
           '".$typ."',
           '".$roomno."',
           '".$arrv."',
           '".$arrivaldate."',
           '".$departure."',
           '".$dDate."',
           '".$idt."',
           '".$emailid."',
           '".$cont."',
           '".$desc."',
           '200',
           '200',
           '200',
           '200',
           'Last Value')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a field which is a reserved word... desc.

Try to enclosed it with '`' character so it should be `desc`.

```
mysql> 
insert into hall_booking
(name,address,event_type,hallNo,arrival_time,
arrival_date,dep_time,dep_date,identity,emailid,contact,total_members,
`desc`,catering,service,decoration,other) values
('$nm','$add','$typ','$roomno','$arrv','$arrivaldate','$departure','$dDate',
 '$idt','$emailid','$cont','$desc','200','200','200','200')
```