# MySQL INSERT statement brings an error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table named ORDER with the title order_date where I need to put the date.

```
function NewOrderID()
    {    
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $t = "INSERT INTO order (order_date) 
              VALUES (' ".$date." ')";
          $query = sprintf($t);    
          $result = mysql_query($query);                        
          if (!$result)
          die(mysql_error());
          return  mysql_insert_id();
    }
```

and I got the following error:

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
    MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order ('order_date')
 VALUES (' 2014-04-29 15:02:40 ')' at line 1
```

Any ideas where I messed up with the query?

Comment: order is reserved keyword use backticks arround ` order

Comment: yes, thank you:) I've jsut changed order tp my_order and everything worked

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I escape reserved words used as column names? MySQL/Create Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order is reserved word in MySQL, you can use back tick(`) around table name

Also you can use MySQL NOW() function for date instead of PHP variable $date

```
$t = "INSERT INTO `order` (order_date) VALUES (NOW())";
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You are using mysql_* functions which are now deprecated and will be removed from PHP in the future. So you need to start using MySQLi or PDO instead.

**Your getting MYSQL error because :**

`order` is reserved keyword of `MYSQL` so you have to use back ticks ` around your tablename :

```
$t = "INSERT INTO `order` (order_date) VALUES ('".$date."')";
```