# How to debug mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a connection to my database:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxxx","xxxxxx");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

which returns no error.

I then try to perform a `mysqli_query`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO entries (name, genre, info , date , website , twebsite, video , tvideo, image, extra_genre)
VALUES ('".$name."', '".$type."', '".$info."', '".$date."', '".$url."', '".$href."', '".$_POST["video"]."', '".$videotype."', 'video images/".$photo."', '".$type2."')");
```

with the alert whether this insertion to the database has worked or not:

```
if($result)
{
echo "Success:";

}
else
{
    echo "error inserting data into database: ";    
}
```

When I perform my code I get the output `error inserting data into database:`

But I have no ides why `$result` is not successful?

### How can I debug it?

Comment: You could also do a `mysqli_error()` after the query I believe. .

Comment: Maybe it's something wrong with your query. Did you try execute it through other means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for `mysqli_error()` function.

Problem here is that `date` is a reserved word, so you have to escape that: `` `date` ``

Comment: sorry I don't understand your comment: `date si reserved word, so you have to escape that: `date``

Comment: Wrong. It is permitted to be used as un-escaped. [**`Reference`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table

Comment: @panther if that link was aimed at me - Read my reference where it clearly states that `date` can be used unquoted...

Comment: @Darren: no, it was for Maximillian. You're write, i didn't know it. Sorry.

Comment: @panther Oh all good! Don't be sorry, we all learn something new every day :-)

Comment: can i write it like this? `VALUES ('$name',.....` instead? @panther

Comment: yes, it's possible but doesn't solve the problem with your query (as mysqli_error). And check for `mysqli_real_escape_string` or better, complete manual how to escape data in SQL queries (kw: SQL injection).

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
echo $result;
```

and then run the sql output.. that should give you an error message.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Getz this is a bad answer but it's answer. If you can't comprehend the problem - please, don't review it. thank you.