# Creating tables in DB results in a lot of exceptions

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

I'm fairly new to SQL and Java so bear with me.

I am trying to reach my DB, create some tables, set it to InnoDB and set some Foreign Keys.
Everything compiles and looks okay, but I end up getting these errors (seems to be located in the JDBC lib):

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'Auditorium'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:848)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:742)
    at CreateDB.createTables(CreateDB.java:35)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

CreateDB.java class looks like this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import static java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver;


public class CreateDB {

static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String database_name = "<DBname>";
static final String DB_URL = "<server>" + "<DBname>";
static final String USER = "*****";
static final String PASS = "*****";
Statement statement = null;
Connection connection = null;


public CreateDB()
{
    try {
        registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // handle errors
    }
}


public void createTables() throws SQLException {
    statement.execute("DROP TABLE Auditorium");
    statement.execute("DROP TABLE Customer");
    statement.execute("DROP TABLE Screening");
    statement.execute("DROP TABLE Ticket");

    String Auditorium = "CREATE TABLE Auditorium "        //Sets name and size of each auditorium
            + "(ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "    //Primary key for Auditorium
            + "Name VARCHAR(10), "                        //Name for specific Auditorium (example: 'aud1')
            + "Row INTEGER NOT NULL, "                    //Amount of rows in specific auditorium
            + "Column INTEGER NOT NULL, "                //Amount of columns in specific auditorium
            + "PRIMARY KEY (ID));";                        //Sets primary key (ID)

    String Screening = "CREATE TABLE Screening "        //Keeps track of what screenings we offer
            + "(ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "    //Primary key for Screening
            + "Auditorium VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, "        //Name for specific Auditorium (example: 'aud1')
            + "Movie VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "            //Movie title
            + "Date DATE NOT NULL, "                    //Specific date the movie is being shown
            + "Time TIME NOT NULL, "                    //What time the movie runs
            + "PRIMARY KEY (ID));";                        //Sets primary key (ID)

    String Customer = "CREATE TABLE Customer "            //Information on the customer
            + "(ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "    //Primary key for Customer
            + "Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "                //Name on customer
            + "Phone INTEGER NOT NULL, "                //Phone on customer
            + "Email VARCHAR(50), "                        //Optional mail on customer
            + "PRIMARY KEY (ID);";                        //Sets primary key (ID)

    String Ticket = "CREATE TABLE Ticket "                //Ticket that customer can buy
            + "(ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "    //Primary key for Ticket
            + "Row INTEGER NOT NULL, "                    //Specific row
            + "Seat INTEGER NOT NULL, "                    //Specific seat
            + "AudID INTEGER NOT NULL, "                //Foreign key references Auditorium(ID)
            + "ScreeningID INTEGER NOT NULL, "            //Foreign key references Screening(ID)
            + "PRIMARY KEY (ID);";                        //Sets primary key (ID)

    statement.executeUpdate(Auditorium);
    statement.executeUpdate(Screening);
    statement.executeUpdate(Customer);
    statement.executeUpdate(Ticket);
}

public void changeEngine() throws SQLException {
    String Auditorium = "ALTER TABLE Auditorium ENGINE=InnoDB;";
    String Screening = "ALTER TABLE Screening ENGINE=InnoDB;";
    String Customer = "ALTER TABLE Customer ENGINE=InnoDB;";
    String Ticket = "ALTER TABLE Ticket ENGINE=InnoDB;";
    statement.execute(Auditorium);
    statement.execute(Screening);
    statement.execute(Customer);
    statement.execute(Ticket);
}

public void applyForeignKeys() throws SQLException {
    String AudID = "ALTER TABLE Ticket ADD FOREIGN KEY (AudID) REFERENCES Auditorium(ID);";
    String ScreeningID = "ALTER TABLE Ticket ADD FOREIGN KEY (ScreeningID) REFERENCES Screening(ID);";
    statement.executeUpdate(AudID);
    statement.executeUpdate(ScreeningID);
}



}
```

My main method is very simply doing so:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    CreateDB c = new CreateDB();
    c.createTables();
    c.changeEngine();
    c.applyForeignKeys();

}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I escape reserved words used as column names? MySQL/Create Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you call `c.createTables()` first in your main method and the tables don't exist.

If the tables don't exist then an error will be returned, such as `table does not exits` because you try to run a `drop` statement on non-existant tables.

Modify `createTables()` to not run `DROP` statements if the tables don't exist.

Since you are using mysql you can do this:

```
statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Auditorium");
```

For Oracle or other databases it would be different.

Answer (score 2):

The line in the stacktrace:

```
 at CreateDB.createTables(CreateDB.java:35)
```

Tells you the line in you code that the error occurs at.

My guess is that line 35 is:

```
statement.execute("DROP TABLE Auditorium");
```

You can't drop a table that doesn't exist.

Try:

```
statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Auditorium");
```

Answer (score 2):

You also forgot a `)` at the end of the `strings` in the following statements:

```
String Customer = "CREATE TABLE Customer "            //Information on the customer
            + "(ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "    //Primary key for Customer
            + "Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "                //Name on customer
            + "Phone INTEGER NOT NULL, "                //Phone on customer
            + "Email VARCHAR(50), "                        //Optional mail on customer
            + "PRIMARY KEY (ID);";                        //Sets primary key (ID)

    String Ticket = "CREATE TABLE Ticket "                //Ticket that customer can buy
            + "(ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "    //Primary key for Ticket
            + "Row INTEGER NOT NULL, "                    //Specific row
            + "Seat INTEGER NOT NULL, "                    //Specific seat
            + "AudID INTEGER NOT NULL, "                //Foreign key references Auditorium(ID)
            + "ScreeningID INTEGER NOT NULL, "            //Foreign key references Screening(ID)
            + "PRIMARY KEY (ID);";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
statement.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Auditorium");
```

Comment: you were faster than me... please update your answer with more details, explaining why to use the `if exists`

Answer (score 0):

In most database engines, there are reserved words which must be marked up in a particular fashion to be used as object names (i.e. table or field names). In MySql, `row` and `column` are reserved words.

Enclosing the column name in backticks will allow a keyword to be used as a column name.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: yes, there are several keywords which can't be used as column names. the same applies to other databases such as Oracle.