# How could I retrieve rows specifying a keyword on PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This is really a dumb question from a beginner, I have a table called "stations" inside my database and on it I have a column called "keywords".
I need to retrieve all those rows that contain one specific keyword (let's say "pizza").
I tried with this but it didn't work:

```
foreach ($stations->result() as $row) 
{       
    foreach ($row->keywords as 'pizza') 
    {  

        <--my code-->
    }
}
```

How could I retrieve all rows that contain "pizza" inside a specific column using PHP?

Comment: You use backtick ` to escape keywords in MySQL, or you can use double quote if ANSI mode is enabled.

Comment: SELECT * FROM <TABLE> WHERE <KEYWORDS> LIKE '%pizza%'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I escape reserved words used as column names? MySQL/Create Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)

Comment: @EricJ. I'm not asking to retrieve data from mysql

Comment: @mrunion I need PHP code

Comment: Where does your PHP code get $stations->result() from? That query needs to be changed to what I sent you.

Comment: `"I'm not asking to retrieve data from mysql"` Excuse me but I beg to differ since you put MySQL in the title, and also tagged it.

Comment: @mrunion it's from the controller, I'm on codeigniter

Comment: codeigniter doesn't allow where clauses in SQL?  Well if that's the case it would prevent adoption, so I doubt that.

Comment: @developerwjk please take a cup of tea and relax, I never say nothing like that...I wrote also that I'm a beginner

Comment: I put it the wrong way, but basically what I meant was: using a where clause is fast. Doing this in PHP like you intend to do is ridiculously slow. And I mean in processing speed not the time it takes to code it.

Comment: @developerwjk Thank you very much for the info, I need to learn lot more,  however I don't understand why my code has a syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `explode()` to turn the list into an array. Then you can use `in_array()`:

```
foreach ($stations->result() as $row) {               
   if ( in_array('pizza', explode(",", $row->keywords) ) ) {
       <--my code-->
   }
}
```

`explode(",", $row->keywords)` turns your comma-separated list into an array.

`in_array('pizza', $array )` returns `TRUE` if pizza is found, otherwise it returns `FALSE`.

Comment: after a BIG headache finally you saved me! Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Instead of parsing it in PHP, you can select only the relevant rows using [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT *
FROM   stations
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET ('pizza', keywords) > 0
```