# PDO greater than less than

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
public function lookForWinner($current_game, $win_cost) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM game" . $current_game . " WHERE from <= ? AND to >= ?";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array($win_cost, $win_cost));
    if ($query->rowCount()) {
        $lookForWinner = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $lookForWinner;
    }       
    return false;
}


$lookforwinner = $objGame->lookForWinner($current_game, $wincost);
```

I am tryin that code but always return false. I checked my parameters : `$current_game = "1"` and `$wincost = 0.19276355021`

wincost is float type. my from and to entities' type are text in mysql. But i also tried with float type and result is same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you using a `text` datatype for float values?

Comment: from and to is a reserved word use back ticks,WHERE \`from\`,to also

Comment: @MarkBaker i tried with float type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape reserved words used as column names? MySQL/Create Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)

Comment: Remove the question marks from your query and put in what your actual values are going to be.

Comment: You`re better off in the long run changing column names,I cant english

Comment: @Caimen: it will not fix the problem. Question marks are valid in this query.

Comment: @Mihai thanks, your first answer works! please write as an answer and i will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks for reserved words,you have 2 here

```
 WHERE `from` <= ? AND `to` >= ?
```

But really change your column names,its annoying always having to escape them