# MySQL throws error when I try to create a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use this code:

```
CREATE TABLE cjlm_messages (uuid VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY, join VARCHAR(500), leave VARCHAR(500));
```

to create a table with columns (uuid--already defined by client), join (a string no longer than 500 characters), and leave (same).
It gives the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to >your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'join >VARCHAR(500), leave VARCHAR(500), PRIMARY KEY (uuid))' at line 1

I'm new to SQL, so any help is appreciated. I briefly looked through the docs and online manuals, and it seems like this should be the correct way.

Comment: `join` is a reserved word.  Change the column name to something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape reserved words used as column names? MySQL/Create Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen While that works, escaping reserved words is a super bad idea.. :)  Unless you want your code to be incomprehensible!

Comment: Notice how the word *join* appears in blue above. You might keep an eye out for that if you have syntax highlighting in your editor. As for *leave*, obviously you can't rely on it for vendor-specific restrictions.

Comment: I would aim at always avoiding reserved words, i would not even include them as part of a table or column name. It just makes for code thats easier to read rather than having to decipher it.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: I agree, however this possible duplicate I added is more of the style: Google and you will find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join is a reserved word.  You cannot use it as a column name.

Comment: Ninja'd. Thanks for the reply! I just found this out.