# SQL Create Table Error in PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm just trying to get database creation/linking/editing working in PHP and I get this error when trying to add a table. Code included. I've tried running this in W3Schools' editor and I also get a syntax error there. Sorry if it's something obvious.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE myguest
(
FirstName int,
Email varchar(255),
PNumber varchar(255),
Price varchar(255),
Desc varchar(255)
);";
```

"Error: CREATE TABLE myguest ( FirstName int, Email varchar(255), PNumber varchar(255), Price varchar(255), Desc varchar(255) );

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Desc varchar(255) )' at line 7"

I'm running MySQL 5.6.17 and PHP 5.5.12 on WAMP server.

Comment: `desc` is a keyword in sql. You can not use it as a column name

Comment: WHy not use `description` as column name?

Comment: @vkp - Not true, you can use it as a column name or even a table name; you just have to wrap it in backticks so it's context is understood.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape reserved words used as column names? MySQL/Create Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Desc` is a reserved word in MySQL, just like trying to create a table called `Table` - it's possible, but you have to make sure MySQL understands the context.

Encapsulate it in backticks.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE myguest
(
`FirstName` int,
`Email` varchar(255),
`PNumber` varchar(255),
`Price` varchar(255),
`Desc` varchar(255)
);";
```

Comment: Thanks! I had removed desc in a previous attempted fix but got the same error. I guess it was the backticks; I didn't see a need for them since the database creation worked without it and I didn't see them in the w3schools example.

Comment: W3Schools is far from perfect.

Comment: Any suggestions for alternatives? I'm open to it. Again, thanks.