# Inner join statement does not seem to work

Tags: sql

I have a simple SQL statement that does not seem to work. I want the of table match_team ("match_id") on the table match ("id").

Therefore I wrote the following INNER JOIN STATEMENT

```
 SELECT * FROM match_team INNER JOIN match ON match_team.match_id = match.id
```

This throws an error however. Any thoughts on what might go wrong here?

Comment: Match is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, it has to be delimited as `"match"`.

Comment: use `databaseName.match`

Comment: @SatishSam, that's no improvement at all...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape reserved words used as column names? MySQL/Create Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And what is the **exact** error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `match` is a reserved word in your RDBMS, you didn't specify your RDBMS, and it really depend on it, but try one of this:

```
SELECT * FROM match_team INNER JOIN `match` ON match_team.match_id = `match`.id
SELECT * FROM match_team INNER JOIN "match" ON match_team.match_id = "match".id
```

I don't know of any SQL language that uses another character for reserved words

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes for avoiding keywords.

```
SELECT * FROM match_team INNER JOIN "match" ON match_team.match_id = "match".id
```

Answer (score 0):

best way to avoid conflict use table with database name. assuming your database is "Master"

```
SELECT * FROM Master.match_team INNER JOIN Master.match ON Master.match_team.match_id = Master.match.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM match_team a
INNER JOIN [match] b ON a.match_id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

First Of all check that you are using your database not the "Master" database ...

use Ctrl+u to access available databases dropdownList or try this :

use [your database name] 
go

### SELECT * FROM match_team INNER JOIN match ON match_team.match_id = match.id

Secondary To avoid Conflicting tables use aliases ... see below for e.g. :

use [your database name] 
go
SELECT * FROM match_team A INNER JOIN match B ON A.match_id = B.id

or start addressing with schema like : dbo.match_team.match_id = dbo.match.id