# Getting a "you have an error in your SQL syntax" error. What is going wrong with this query?

Tags: c#, mysql

**What I am doing**: I am making a Outlook add-in for making firewall policy change request using C# and VisualStudio. A part of the add-in is the user inputting IP addresses.

**What I want**: Take IP address input from the user and add it to the Mysql DB , and show the added IP's in a DataGridView in the form itself

**How it should work**:

[image: imgur link of the snapshot of the form]

**What I am getting**:

[image: imgur link of the error prompt]

**My Code:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static string conString = "Server=localhost;Database=aWork;uid=root;Pwd=password";
    MySqlConnection mson = new MySqlConnection(conString);
    MySqlCommand mcd;
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Datagridview properties
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 8;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ID" ;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Source IP" ;
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Source Misc. IP" ;
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Destination IP";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Misc. Destination IP";
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Application" ;
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name = "Protocol";
        dataGridView1.Columns[7].Name = "Port" ;

        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

        //Selection Mode
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;





    }


    //INSERT INTO DB
    private void add(string source_IP, string source_Misc_IP, string Dest_IP, string Misc_Dest_IP, string app, string Protocol , string port)
    {
        //SQL STMT
        string sql = "INSERT INTO table1(Source IP,Source Misc. IP,Destination IP,Misc. Destination IP,Application,Protocol,Port) VALUES ('" + ipAddressControl1.ToString() + "','" + ipAddressControl2.ToString() + "','" + ipAddressControl3.ToString() + "','" + ipAddressControl4.ToString() + "','" + ipAddressControl5.ToString() + "','" + ipAddressControl6.ToString() + "','" + ipAddressControl7.ToString() + "')";
        mcd = new MySqlCommand(sql, mson);

        //OPEN MSON[CON] AND EXEC INSERT
        try
        {
            mson.Open();
            if (mcd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Inserted Successfully ");
            }
            mson.Close();

            retrieve();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            mson.Close();

        }
    }  private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //BUTTON FOR ADDING TO THE DB
    {
        add(ipAddressControl1.ToString(), ipAddressControl2.ToString(), ipAddressControl3.ToString(), ipAddressControl4.ToString(), ipAddressControl5.ToString(), ipAddressControl6.ToString(), ipAddressControl7.ToString());
    }
```

My field is primarily Android Dev and so I am not familiar with making SQL connections.

I have to furthermore add buttons to edit and delete this data in the datagridview (for which I have already written the code,which is not copy-pasted above).

Comment: Ideally, you don't include spaces in your column names for any SQL product, since you'll always (as here) have to remember to *escape* them in every query you write with them. I believe in MySQL backticks are used for escaping.

Comment: 1: I don't know about mysql specifically, but in most RDBMS, you need to use special syntax if your column names have spaces in. For example, in SQL Server, it would be `[Source IP], [Source Misc. IP], ...` - or better: *don't use those names* (`SourceIP` would be fine); 2: that code is ripe for SQL injection - please please please learn about (and use) parameters; [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2889884/23354) agrees with @Damien_The_Unbeliever that backticks (`\`Source IP\``) are the mysql escape syntax

Comment: Sorry , this is my first ever program using c# and mysql. I dont even know properly what SQL injection is! But I will re-edit and remove all the spaces in the names(i hope it wont give me any errors) and get back to you guys :)

Comment: @NoHolidays and the full stops; `SourceMiscIP` is a reasonable column name; `Source Misc. IP` is just masochistic; note that we're only talking about the columns defined at the database in the `table1` table; it doesn't really matter so much what `dataGridView1.Columns[n].Name` is - no code cares about that except UI designers / code-generators

Comment: The good news is that it adds to the db. The bad news is that it throws multiple error handling exception and prompts before and after it does it[though if you press continue in the prompt , you can continue] I suppose the issue lies in the automatically generated scripts , which still have the older names[with the spaces and periods] . And my justification for adding them was to improve readability of the end user. I thought I was playing by the rules

Comment: hey guys , thanks for all your input. wouldnt have been able to do it without you two :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this out with the help of @Damien_The_Unbeliever and @Marc Gravell♦
 I am posting this answer so that it may help someone in the future

First of all , in my above code I have made the horrible mistake here:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO table1(Source IP,Source Misc. IP,Destination IP,Misc. Destination IP,Application,Protocol,Port) VALUES ('" + ipAddressControl1.ToString() + "','" + ipAddressControl2.ToString() + "','" + ipAddressControl3.ToString() + "','" + ipAddressControl4.ToString() + "','" + ipAddressControl5.ToString() + "','" + ipAddressControl6.ToString() + "','" + ipAddressControl7.ToString() + "')";
```

Instead , it should be something like :

```
"string sql = "INSERT INTO table1(SourceIP,SourceMiscIP,DestinationIP,MiscDestinationIP,Application,Protocol,Port) VALUES ('" + source_IP + "','" + source_Misc_IP + "','" + Dest_IP + "','" + Misc_Dest_IP + "','" + app + "','" + Protocol + "','" + port + "')";
```

then , ofc I made the noob mistake of using spaces and periods , because of which I had to edit not only my code , but the computer generated .cs files

*[had to search through and edit >1700 lines of code! Though ctrl+f helped a lot...]*

It was very tedious , but I learned my lessons

Thank you to all for helping me out :)

Have a great day ahead!