# How to select multiple fields with mysql

Tags: mysql

This gives me errors. How do I need to rewrite it?

I want to have the query return both the subject and that row's corresponding count.

`SELECT (SELECT subject FROM marks) AS subject, (SELECT count FROM marks) AS count WHERE usr = 'username'`

Comment: What do you mean by "that row's corresponding count"? `count` is a function that counts rows; it doesn't work on one row. Or do you have a column named `"count"`? (If so, please rename the column to something other than a MySQL function name.)  Can you give us an example (with data) of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @TedHopp I will rename, thanks!

Comment: Relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table

Comment: @TedHopp, `COUNT` is not a reserved keyword.

Comment: @shmosel - No, but it's the same fix in the case of a column name being the same as a function name.

Comment: @TedHopp There's no problem with naming a column the same as a function name. [Proof](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/303612/1/0)

Comment: @shmosel - How about that. I was obviously off on the wrong track.

Answer (score 2):

The subqueries are not required and are breaking your relationship.  Try this:

```
SELECT subject, `count` FROM marks WHERE usr = 'username';
```

I think `count` is a column in your table? If so, as @TedHopp points out, since `count` is also a mysql built-in function, you'll have to escape it to refer to the column name.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3cd1/1 is a corresponding fiddle.

Comment: It is a column. If I rename it, how do I select both?

Comment: @Nemo-Omen - I think Dan just showed you.

Comment: Same way you select both if you _don't_ rename it, just specify the correct name in either case.  Or, you can always use the backticks "`" to escape if you don't want to rename.  Using reserved keywords as column names isn't "wrong" per se, but it does force you to escape.

Comment: `COUNT` is not a reserved keywords. See my comments on the question.

Comment: @shmosel, you're arguing semantics, but technically it's a function ( an aggregate function to be exact).  The answers address this, so the difference is irrelevant.

Comment: Function names don't need to be escaped. How is that semantics?

Comment: but the OP is attempting to refer to a *column* not the function with the same name.

Comment: Which is not at all a problem. Did you read my comments on the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT subject, COUNT(subject) `count`
FROM marks
WHERE usr = 'username'
GROUP BY subject
```