# SQL creating table error at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I keep getting error in my code
: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$sql = "CREATE TABLE Kodu(
        ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 ' at line 1"

I even tried this code in SQLfiddle and it gave me the same error. Can somebody please help me spot the error? thanks

```
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE Kodu(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Dateoforder DATE NOT NULL,
    Contract VARCHAR(10),
    Order INT NOT NULL,
    Office VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Ship VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 

)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Kodu(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Dateoforder DATE NOT NULL,
    Contract VARCHAR(10),
    OrderNumber INT NOT NULL,
    Office VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Ship VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
)
```

You need to change `Order` with another name  because order is a protected word in SQL

Or wrap into quotes or backtick the word like this (if ANSI mode is enabled):

```
   CREATE TABLE Kodu(
        ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        Dateoforder DATE NOT NULL,
        Contract VARCHAR(10),
        "Order" INT NOT NULL,
        Office VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        Ship VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the keyword `order`.

You have to escape the work either using back ticks or surrounding with quotes if ansi mode is enabled.

Please read more [How do I escape reserved words used as column names? MySQL/Create Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)

The better recommendation is to use another word instead of escaping.