# You have an error in your SQL syntax ... to use near '-mat,matricule-mat,qte-mat,type-mat,service,fournisseur) VALUES ('souris',22,555' at line 1'

Tags: c#, mysql

```
private void add(string design, string matricule, string qte, string type, string service, string fournisseur)
{
    string sql = "INSERT INTO db(designation-mat,matricule-mat,qte-mat,type-mat,service,fournisseur) VALUES (@DESIGN,@MATRICULE,@QTE,@TYPE,@SERVICE,@FOURNISSEUR)";
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESIGN", design);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MATRICULE", Convert.ToInt32(matricule));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTE", Convert.ToInt32(qte));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TYPE", type);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SERVICE", service);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FOURNISSEUR", fournisseur);

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            cleartxts();
            MessageBox.Show("SuccessFuly Inserted!");
        }

        con.Close();
        retrieve();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps column  with hypens like `designation-mat` need to be quoted: `"designation-mat"`, or backticks (`\``) or however it's done in MySQL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table

Comment: can you provide a proper description so that we can able to help you

Comment: Please add a body to your question not just code.  A title should bring people to your question and not be entire question in of itself.

Comment: ok i will edit the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use ` around the column names:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO db (`designation-mat`, `matricule-mat`, `qte-mat`, `type-mat`, service, fournisseur) VALUES (@DESIGN, @MATRICULE, @QTE, @TYPE, @SERVICE, @FOURNISSEUR)";
```

It is brackets [...] if you use SQL Server.