# VB.net - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have problem, I want to input data in my database but I get an error message (you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to ypur MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'unique, partno, boxs, pcs, modul, p_lane) VALUES (1, 'T103','16581-57020',3,1'  at line 1)

but after checking the syntax I used accordingly

this is my code

```
 ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "TAPPING PLAN TMC" Then
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("insert into s_unpackingtmc(no, unique, partno, boxs, pcs, modul, p_lane) VALUES (@Column1, @Column2, @Column3, @Column4, @Column5, @Column6, @Column7)", conn)
        Try


            For i As Integer = 0 To (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2)

                no1 = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
                unique1 = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
                partno1 = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
                boxs1 = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
                pcs1 = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
                modul1 = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
                plane1 = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column1", no1)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column2", unique1)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column3", partno1)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column4", boxs1)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column5", pcs1)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column6", modul1)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column7", plane1)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            Next
            MsgBox("Data Berhasil Diupload", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Information")
            Call tampildata3()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Information")
            cmd.Dispose()
            Call tampildata3()



        End Try
```

Comment: Perhaps because `unique` is a reserved word? I believe the identifier quoting character in MariaDB is a backtick, so I'd suggest trying ``... no, `unique`, partno, ...`` and see if you have any luck.

Comment: @TylerRoper okk thanks,  the problem is solve I replace variable unique  with other variable

Answer (score 0):

According to MariaDB documentation [keywords](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/) and [constraints](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/#unique), `UNIQUE` is a reserved keyword for table unique constraint definition:

> The UNIQUE keyword means that the index will not accept duplicated
>   values, except for NULLs. An error will raise if you try to insert
>   duplicate values in a UNIQUE index.
>
> For UNIQUE keys, PRIMARY KEYs and FOREIGN KEYs, you can specify a name
>   for the constraint, using the CONSTRAINT keyword. That name will be
>   used in error messages.

You can use either backtick or double quotes depending on each modes (standard or ANSI SQL mode respectively, see [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)) or rename it to other non-keyword identifier:

**Standard mode**

```
insert into s_unpackingtmc(no, `unique`, partno, boxs, pcs, modul, p_lane) VALUES (@Column1, @Column2, @Column3, @Column4, @Column5, @Column6, @Column7)
```

**ANSI SQL mode**

```
insert into s_unpackingtmc(no, "unique", partno, boxs, pcs, modul, p_lane) VALUES (@Column1, @Column2, @Column3, @Column4, @Column5, @Column6, @Column7)
```