# mysql insert error with column name is "key"

Tags: mysql, isql

my table header is follow:
`id:name:key:value`

when insert something using below sql syntax shows error:
`insert table( name, key, value) value ("jack","mobile","18561436678")`

Comment: There is `"` missing that's why you are getting error. `"18561436678` should be `"18561436678"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape reserved words used as column names? MySQL/Create Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)

Comment: `key` is a reserved word, you need to escape it in backticks i.e. `\`key\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
 insert table( `name`, `key`, `value`) value ("jack","mobile","18561436678");
```

Answer (score 0):

OH , I found the answer by Google,
the reason is table column name "key" is conflicted  with mysql definded some word,
should use below:
`insert table( name,`key`,`value`) value ("jack","mobile","18561436678")`

```
key to `key`
value to `vlue`
```