# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

first i created a 2 sql table one is functioning and the other is not the code in my java class is

```
    try {                           
            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pattable(surname,first,middle,add,contact,email,bdate,genderr) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
            ps1.setString(1, surname);
            ps1.setString(2, first);
            ps1.setString(3, middle);
            ps1.setString(4, add);
            ps1.setString(5, contact);
            ps1.setString(6, email);
            ps1.setString(7, bdate);
            ps1.setString(8, genderr);
            ps1.execute(); 
            ps1.close();
            con.close();
    }
            catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

According to console the error might be triggering at line ps1.execute in java with the line "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add,contact,email,bdate,genderr)" please help
Thanks for the Reply really need it for case study :)

Comment: instead if u want the add column name u can use [add] this will be acceptable in sql server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have one column name `add` ,this is reserved keyword in mysql .check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) you cannot use that as your column name that the reason of error you are getting .

Comment: @JustaNewProgrammer check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, I'd review https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp to find your problem.