# error using mydumper since move to mysql8 caused by character `\x0A` used for new lines

Tags: mysql-8.0

I am getting an error which seem to be related to the new line character not being interpreted during import of a backup created with `mydumper`.

- MySQL Server version: 8.0.19-10
- mydumper version: mydumper 0.9.5, built against MySQL 5.7.21-21

I have tried the following:

- `myloader -d .`
- `cat console.size-schema.sql | mysql console`

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"size" (\x0A  "id" int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\x0A  "name" varchar(255) NOT NUL' at line 1
```

The file seems normal when I use `cat`

```
$ cat console.size-schema.sql 
/*!40101 SET NAMES binary*/;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0*/;

/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
CREATE TABLE "size" (
  "id" int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  "label" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  "width" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "height" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "depth" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "deleted_at" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "created_at" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "updated_at" int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=522 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql uses " for escaping only in ANSI mode, by default it uses back tick

[How do I escape reserved words used as column names? MySQL/Create Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)

my personal preference is to use back tick everywhere as this setting is widely used, making it easier for mysql import/export via dump files

Comment: Turns out old server had `ANSI_QUOTES` and new server didn't. The `\x0A` looked like it was the issue, but was actually the `"`.  Thanks for the help.