# Attempting to INSERT values into a MySQL DB from C# code within a form, but getting "Column cannot be NULL

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, webforms

All - thanks in advance for your time.  So, background info - I am trying to create a form for contact registration using C# to pass the information into my MySql DB.  If I use the query directly in the code, it works.  However, I have read that you should use a stored procedure for security.  So, working code is:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Contacts (contactID,last_name,first_name,address,city,state,zip_code,email_address,newsletter,is_Cell) VALUES (@ciD,@ln, @fn, @add, @city, @state, @zip, @email, @news, @cell)";
                //cmd.CommandText = "insert_contact";
                //cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@cID", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ln", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@fn", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@add", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@state", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@zip", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@news", MySqlDbType.Bit);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@cell", MySqlDbType.Bit);

                cmd.Parameters["@cID"].Value = default;
                cmd.Parameters["@ln"].Value = lastName_TextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@fn"].Value = firstName_TextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@add"].Value = address_TextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@city"].Value = city_TextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@state"].Value = state_DropDown.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@zip"].Value = zipCode_TextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@email"].Value = email_TextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters["@news"].Value = newsletter_CheckBox.Checked;
                cmd.Parameters["@cell"].Value = cell_CheckBox.Checked;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
```

However, when I change the following lines to this, I get the "cannot be NULL error":

```
 conn.Open();
                //cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Contacts (contactID,last_name,first_name,address,city,state,zip_code,email_address,newsletter,is_Cell) VALUES (@ciD,@ln, @fn, @add, @city, @state, @zip, @email, @news, @cell)";
                cmd.CommandText = "insert_contact";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

My stored procedure on the DB is (I suspect this is where the error may be):

```
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO Contacts (contactID,last_name,first_name,address,city,state,zip_code,email_address,newsletter,is_Cell) 
 VALUES (@ciD,@ln, @fn, @add, @city, @state, @zip, @email, @news, @cell);
 END
```

I have attempted the following, with the accompanying errors:

•  Changed the "@" in the stored procedures to a "?"     -(Get an error in SQL Syntax)

•  Changing all of the columns to accept a NULL value.   -(All columns then have a NULL value).

My apologies if this is something easy - just starting out learning.

Thanks in advance!

- Pherix

Comment: Hints for debug & fix: Check whether which table column is NOT NULLABLE, and you are providing NULL value to that column or you didn't provide any value to that column. Would be great if you can also provide the table schema.

Comment: And does your Stored Procedure script contains parameters such `CREATE PROCEDURE insert_contact (@ciD varchar, /* The rest parameters */)`? As you just post the part of the Stored Proc. Make sure that in your C# code you provide all the parameters with the correct type and value according to the Stored Proc.'s parameters.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Contacts` (
  `contactID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `pref_phone` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `newsletter` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_Cell` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contactID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_address` (`email_address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: I used MySql Workbench to create the procedure, and it shows this:

CREATE DEFINER=`<username is here>`@`%` PROCEDURE `insert_contact`()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Contacts (contactID,last_name,first_name,address,city,state,zip_code,email_address,newsletter,is_Cell) 
VALUES (@cID, @ln, @fn, @add, @city, @state, @zip, @email, @news, @cell);
END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally found what the Stored Procedure liked:

```
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO Contacts 
(last_name,first_name,address,city,state,zip_code,email_address,newsletter,is_Cell) 
VALUES 
(ln, fn, address, city, state, zip, email, news, cell); 

END
```

Apparently, it did not like the "@" in front of the passed values.

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert_contact` stored procedure have to provide the parameters (with the type) as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_contact
(
    IN cID VARCHAR,
    IN ln VARCHAR(30),
    IN fn VARCHAR(45),
    IN `add` VARCHAR(30),
    IN city VARCHAR(30),
    IN state VARCHAR(10),
    IN zip VARCHAR(20),
    IN email VARCHAR(45),
    IN news bit,
    IN cell bit,
)

BEGIN 

INSERT INTO Contacts 
(contactID,last_name,first_name,address,city,state,zip_code,email_address,newsletter,is_Cell) 
VALUES 
(@cID, @ln, @fn, @add, @city, @state, @zip, @email, @news, @cell); 

END
```

And in case there is any parameter which conflict with MySQL reserved words, you need to [escape the reserved words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2889871/8017690) with single quotes.

Note:

Your `contactID` column was `int(11)` type but you provide the `cID` parameter as `VARCHAR` type. You need to take concern that the column type was unmatched and possible lead an exception.

---

**Reference**

[MySQL - Working with Stored Procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html)