# When are square brackets not to be used?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax

I understand that square brackets allow the use of reserved names or previously disallowed characters such as spaces in your identifiers.  I thought adding them everywhere was good practice.  (See [What is the use of the square brackets [] in sql statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898/what-is-the-use-of-the-square-brackets-in-sql-statements))

However, I notice that when I use them in the COL_LENGTH function, I get some unexpected results:

```
SELECT COL_LENGTH(N'[TestTable]', N'[RatingID]')    -- Returns NULL
SELECT COL_LENGTH(N'TestTable', N'[RatingID]')      -- Returns NULL
SELECT COL_LENGTH(N'[TestTable]', N'RatingID')      -- Returns 10
SELECT COL_LENGTH(N'TestTable', N'RatingID')        -- Returns 10
```

I can see that by defining the column name in single quotes, the square brackets become redundant, but I don't understand why they break the call.  That square brackets work for the table argument increases my confusion.

Is there a rule for when square brackets *shouldn't* be used?

Comment: Also don't want to use brackets with #temp.  At least I have had trouble with brackets and #temp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not pass square brackets into functions that take strings only use in actual SQL statements. The function is looking for a table with the name including the square brackets.

Comment: Right, basically SQL Server is going to apply `QUOTENAME()` for you inside of certain functions. The problem is that it is inconsistent - sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. I don't know of a handy list that distinguishes...