# What is the difference between square brackets and single quotes for aliasing in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, alias, quotes, brackets

I have seen some people alias column names using single quotes eg:

```
select orderID 'Order No' from orders
```

and others use square brackets eg:

```
select orderID [Order No] from orders
```

I tend to use square brackets. Is there any preference/difference?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

To answer the question "is there any preference/difference":

Yes, there are as many preferences as there are opinions, but be careful whose preferences you adopt.

As a best practice, it is advisable to write portable SQL if it doesn't require any extra effort.

For your specific sample, it is just as easy to write a portable query...

```
select OrderId as "Order Id" from Orders
```

... as it is to write a non-portable one:

```
select OrderId as [Order Id] from Orders
```

It is preferable not to write non-standard SQL when there is an equivalent portable form of the same number of keystrokes.

The proliferation of [] for escaping is due to tools like SQL Server Management Studio and MS Access query builders, which lazily escape everything. It may never occur to a developer who spends his/her career in SQL Server, but the brackets have caused a lot of expense over the years porting Access and SQL Server apps to other database platforms. The same goes for Oracle tools that quote everything. Untrained developers see the DDL as examples, and then proceed to use the same style when writing by hand. It is a hard cycle to break until tools improve and we demand better. In Oracle, quoting, combined with mixed casing, results in case sensitive databases. I have seen projects where people quoted every identifier in the database, and I had the feeling I was in The Land of The Lost where the developers had evolved on an island without documentation or best practice articles.

If you write your DDL, from the start, with normalized, legal identifiers (use OrderId, or order_Id instead of [Order Id], you don't worry about the mythical keyword that might need escape characters; the database will inform you when you've used a reserved word. I can count on one finger the times we've ever upgraded an app from one version of SQL Server to another and had any breakage due to *new* reserved words.

This is often the subject of heated debate, so if you think about it another way:

C# programmers don't escape all their variables with @, even though it is legal to do so. That would be considered an odd practice, and would be the subject of ridicule on StackOverflow. Escaping should be for the edge cases. But the same developers that write conforming C# identifiers don't mind escaping every single identifier in their SQL, writing terribly ugly, non-portable SQL "code". As a consultant, I've met more than one SQL Server programmer who honestly thought [] was required syntax. I don't blame the developers; I blame the tools.

Comment: Upvote for talking about standards, and portability between systems

Comment: Great correlated example to avoid bad practices in SQL - `C# programmers don't escape all their variables with @, even though it is legal to do so`.

Comment: Upvote from me, too. To be honest, I think Microsoft stick to the Square Brackets either to annoy everybody else or to make migration just a little bit harder.

Comment: I'm so happy I read this! I am new to SQL development and I absolutely fall under the category of "SQL Server programmers who honestly thought [] was required syntax." Thank you for setting me straight.

Comment: @cOborski I'm happy it helped you as well!

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what settings you have in force whether `'`s are valid or not. And you missed out `"`. See [Delimited Identifiers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027(v=sql.105).aspx):

> When QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is set to ON, SQL Server follows the ISO rules for the use of double quotation marks (")and the single quotation mark (') in SQL statements. For example:
>
> - Double quotation marks can be used only to delimit identifiers. They cannot be used to delimit character strings.
> - Single quotation marks must be used to enclose character strings. They cannot be used to delimit identifiers.

---

> When QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is set to OFF, SQL Server uses the following rules for single and double quotation marks:
>
> - Quotation marks cannot be used to delimit identifiers. Instead, brackets have to be used as delimiters.
> - Single or double quotation marks can be used to enclose character strings.

And finally:

> Delimiters in brackets can always be used, regardless of the setting of QUOTED_IDENTIFIER

Where, in all of the above quotes, when they refer to brackets they're talking about `[]` brackets.

Comment: This doesn't affect how `select 1 as 'foo'` is interpreted.

Answer (score 5):

Single quotes are more readable. As demonstrated above, highlighted in red.

MySQL uses `backticks` to escape special characters.

MSSQL can either use "double quotes" or [brackets] for identifiers (tables, columns, etc)
and 'single quotes' for character strings or aliases.

The square brackets are used primarily to encapsulate objects so that special characters such as spaces, periods or hyphens do not throw syntax errors.

I would recommend using the 'as' keyword before your column aliases - it's much more readable.

```
select [column with spaces] as 'my col' from "table with spaces" where n = 'foo'
select "column with spaces" as 'my col' from [table with spaces] where n = 'foo'
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer to be more specific and added more examples.

Comment: Mike - single quotes should not be used for column aliases either on any DBMS, because single-quoted identifiers can be misinterpreted as character literals by built-in functions. To see why, try this code:  `select sum ('foo') from (select 1 as 'foo') x`

Comment: @JustinGrant "just because you can, doesn't mean you should" - grandma

Comment: Mike: I might add that MySQL, and its successor MariaDB, have the option to switch to ANSI mode, either for the session or permanently (which I have done on my own server). In ANSI mode, double quotes are then used as delimiters instead of strings.

Answer (score 2):

The quote approach enables you to do this:

```
SELECT 1 AS 'bla[]bla'
```

Comment: or this: `select 1 as [bla'bla]`

Comment: As [`QUOTENAME`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) shows, it's possible to delimit a name containing square brackets using the square brackets form: `[bla[]]bla]`

Comment: Quoting is for wusses, and IBM agrees, see [what you can do with a table named from](https://books.google.com/books?id=EoSNYVb5LAsC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=sql+%22select+from+from%22&source=bl&ots=-dRlUey7CR&sig=YdwWlfCwspfYYyfQk6n9DuOFMYY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AG6VVZvGJ8fNsAWdxYqwAg&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=sql%20%22select%20from%20from%22&f=false) or [with a table named where](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/the_mysterious_case_of_the_empty_where49?lang=en), in DB2.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Justin Grant in a comment on this thread - posting this is as a full answer for visibility.

If we accept that generally preferences are subjective, but consistency is desirable, then in terms of actual differences, there's a good reason not to use single quotes `'`. If you need to use e.g. an aggregate function on a column whose name requires quoting, single quotes will get you into trouble (code directly copy/paste from Justin's comment):

```
select sum ('foo') from (select 1 as 'foo') x
```

This is enough reason, in my opinion, not to use single quotes - there are cases in which you cannot use them, which hampers consistency.

Double quotes `"` or brackets `[]` are, then, the only ways to go. This comes down to what kind of consistency you value more - consistency with code that SQL Server specific tools might produce, which will use brackets, or adherence to the ANSI standard, which specifies double quotes. In a sufficiently engrained Microsoft environment, brackets may make more sense. Absent that, double quotes are probably better practice.