# Mysql inner join column with spaces

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables which are the customers table and orders table.
Basically my problem is that it always give me an error which is 'unknown field list'.
I have tried in phpmyadmin XAMPP it works the only problem is that when I use it in VS studio c# it gives me an error.
I'm confused the back ticks '`' don't work but the back ticks work on localhost.
Please help me.

This is my sql syntax:

```
SQL = "SELECT o.`Order ID`, o.Description, o.Amount 
       FROM tbl_orders AS o 
           INNER JOIN tbl_customers AS c ON o.`Order ID` = c.`Order ID` 
       WHERE c.`Customer ID` = '" + cust_id + "'";
            cmd.Connection = dbCon;
            cmd.CommandText = SQL;
            rdr= cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(rdr);
```

Comment: Is your database engine SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: My database engine is MySQL.
The back ticks work on localhost.
But in VS studio it gives me an error.
I'm confused. Geez.

Answer (score 1):

Have tried deleting and retyping the ` around the column names incase it didnt copy correctly. Also try putting a @ before the string so.

```
SQL = @"<the sql>";
```

this works on mysql xampp

```
 MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(@"Server=localhost;Database=test;");
        var sql = @"SELECT o.`Order ID`, o.Description, o.Amount 
   FROM tbl_orders AS o 
       INNER JOIN tbl_customers AS c ON o.`Order ID` = c.`Order ID` 
   WHERE c.`Customer ID` = 1";
        sqlConnection.Open();
        MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql,sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: ok i will recreate this scenario and get back to you in a minute

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MysqlException: Unknown column 'o.Order ID' in 'field list'

Comment: what version of sqlServer are you using?

Comment: I'm using XAMPP MySql.. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Order ID]...

Comment: i dont know why it wont work on my pc but thank you for your help i really appreciate it. i guess i will use nested queries.

Answer (score 0):

Columns with spaces in their name should be enclosed in square brackets.

Try

```
SQL = "SELECT o.[Order ID], o.Description, o.Amount 
       FROM tbl_orders AS o 
           INNER JOIN tbl_customers AS c ON o.[Order ID] = c.[Order ID] 
       WHERE c.[Customer ID] = '" + cust_id + "'";
            cmd.Connection = dbCon;
            cmd.CommandText = SQL;
            rdr= cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(rdr);
```

http://tinyurl.com/qcf45vf

[What is the use of the square brackets [] in sql statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52898/1857669)

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Order ID]...

Comment: Can you try removing the AS when setting the alias.
So just 
...
FROM tbl_orders o INNER JOIN tbl_customers c
...

Comment: the backticks work on localhost i just don't know why it won't work on vs studio.

Comment: What MySQL connector version are you using in your VS project?

Comment: MySQL Connector Net 6.2.4

Comment: Download the NuGet package manager extension for VS if you don't have it, this just makes package management a breeze then update your MySQL connector in your project to 6.7.4. 
the package is called "MySql.Data"
I have just recreated your scenario on my localhost MySQL server and you original query runs fine when you remove the "AS" strings in the alias naming.
Might also be worth sharing your full method for creating and executing the query (blank out any con strings) etc just to make sure you are using all the correct variable types.

Comment: i dont know why it wont work on my pc but thank you for your help i really appreciate it. i guess i will use nested queries.