# SQL update statement error with OLEDB

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, oledbconnection

The error is "Syntax error in UPDATE Statement"

```
string id = lblUserID.Text;
DB_Connection.con.Open();
string sql = "UPDATE TblUser SET LastName = @LastName,FirstName = @FirstName,MI = @MI,UserLevel = @UserLevel,Username = @Username,Password = @Password WHERE UserID = '" + id + "'";
DB_Connection.command = new OleDbCommand(sql, DB_Connection.con);

DB_Connection.command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
DB_Connection.command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
DB_Connection.command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MI", txtMI.Text);
DB_Connection.command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserLevel", cmbUserLevel.Text);
DB_Connection.command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
DB_Connection.command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
DB_Connection.command.ExecuteNonQuery();
DB_Connection.con.Close();
```

Comment: So maybe you should use the debugger and look at that `sql` string? Or print it out?

Comment: Set this block in a try catch and update your post with the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely `UserID` is a number in your table, but the apostrophes you've surrounded the value with means you're trying to assign a string literal to a number column.

Parameterize the user id too:

```
string sql = "UPDATE TblUser SET ..... WHERE UserID = @UserId";

...

var userId = int.Parse(lblUserID.Text);  // will throw exception if not a number
DB_Connection.command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);

...
...
```

---

Unrelated, but another observation. Instead of using whatever class-level structure `DB_Connection` is, consider using `using` statements and create the connection and command locally, as you need them.

The `using` statement will close the connection so you don't have to call `Close()` explicitly (which, incidentally, won't run if an exception is thrown in your method).

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in the query.  Apparently it seems following reason:

1. May be you are using single quote for userID. Assuming if userID is integer in database then you have to remove single quotes.
2. Another possibility,  may be you are missing adding brackets around database table column names. Which match the names of reserved words in SQL.

Example:

```
[Password] = @Password
```

Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898/what-is-the-use-of-the-square-brackets-in-sql-statements) to understand why square brackets are useful,  although not mandatory.

Here is [list of reserved words](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) for Microsoft OLE DB Provider.

Comment: I think necessary when your DB column match with reserved words of SQL server.

Comment: 1. The OP may or may not be using SQL Server. 2. It's not usually necessary, and only `Password` is a reserved word.

Comment: @JohnSaunders. I have specified Password column in the example.  If you think my answer is not good then plz edit.