# C# SqlCeCommand parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

Code:

```
SqlCeCommand addBookHistoryQuery = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO rooms_history (room_id,[user],data_wynajecia,data_zwolnienia,id) VALUES (@room_id, @user, @data_wynajecia, @data_zwolnienia, @id)", connection);
```

Can anyone remind me what was doing **[ ]** with parameter? ([user])

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brackets are typically used around names that are reserved keywords in SQL, or to get around special characters. This is a duplicate of [What is the use of the square brackets [] in sql statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898/what-is-the-use-of-the-square-brackets-in-sql-statements) though.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for stupid question. :P