# SQL [int] versus int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Recently I am working with SQL language. I found two ways of declaring [temporary table variables(starting with @)](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/). My question is:

Is there any difference between them?

```
DECLARE
    @variable1 [int],
    @variable2 int
```

Comment: This has nothing to see with tables. Both declarations means the same.

Comment: no, there is no difference
have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898/what-is-the-use-of-the-square-brackets-in-sql-statements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of the square brackets \[\] in sql statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898/what-is-the-use-of-the-square-brackets-in-sql-statements)

Comment: There are many flavours of SQL. Tag your question with the system you are using ([tag:sql-server], it seems)

Comment: Outside of micosoft (and possibly Sybase) the `[]` are a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in this instance. However, the square brackets are used as delimiters if you [have special characters that need identifying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52901/3133680) - for example if you name a column "First Name", you'll need square brackets to escape the space character.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful!

Comment: Adding brackets can cause a problem in some instances `DECLARE @a double precision; /* valid */` `DECLARE @b [double precision]; /* invalid */`

Answer (score 0):

Nope those are the same. Typing it with the brackets is just extra keystrokes.