# Why i am getting error while queries in mssql like select * from DBname.dbo.tablename?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Here AS is dbname and dbo is schema and MULTIPLE_SUBSCRIBERS is a table.

Error as follows:

> [image]
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Kindly help.

Comment: Error as follows:Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AS` is a keyword. The way you added it to the sql statement tells SQL Server to interpret it as such.

To use the database name `AS`, you need to use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [AS].dbo.MULTIPLE_SUBSCRIBERS;
```

When using square bracket, SQL Server will always interpret the text as a name. This also works for names with spaces. For more see: [What is the use of the square brackets [] in sql statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898/what-is-the-use-of-the-square-brackets-in-sql-statements)

Comment: Thanks you so much rollstuhlfahrer. Its working fine after adding above characters.