# Are [ ] needed in a SQL query

Tags: sql, database, ssms-2016

[image: SQL Query]

I was wondering if the [ ] are needed? and what is the benefit of using them?

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of the square brackets \[\] in sql statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898/what-is-the-use-of-the-square-brackets-in-sql-statements)

Comment: I would use `\`table name\`` instead for escaping when you have white spaces in your names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square braces are never needed in a standard SQL query, because they are not part of the standard.

Some databases (notably SQL Server and related dialects) use square braces as escape characters for identifiers.  Identifiers that contain only letters, digits, and underscore (for the most part) and that are not reserved words do not need to be escaped.  I strongly advise that all your identifiers follow these rules.

In your sample query, the identifiers are all fine.  They do not need to be escaped.  The square braces are just visual clutter.

Comment: @Origin27 I would say that it's generally bad practice to use them, because using them allows you to use bad names for your databases, tables, and columns.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Origin27 . . . I agree with Tim.  Further, they make queries harder to write and to read.