# Error in insert query in visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm new in this field. Trying to insert the values from textbox to my database table, but I get an error at

```
 adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

```
SqlCommand command;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(); 

String sql = "insert into NewName values('" + first_Name.Text + "','" + last_Name.Text + "','" + user.Text + "','" + email.Text + "','" + password.Text + "','" + contact.Text + "')";

command = new SqlCommand(sql,con);

adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql,con); 

// this line here is showing the error
adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.Dispose();
con.Close();
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really have a table named "table"?

Comment: `table` is a SQL reserved word, do you really have a table called table?

Comment: @DavidG You and I, we speak the same language....

Comment: yes .my table name is table

Comment: @NavidAnjum, as far as I know sql-server does not even allow you to create a table with name..table. If  it does I assume you are using brackets like: [table], however I don't believe you can

Comment: I suggest thinking of a better name for your table, other than `table`. I also **strongly** recommend parametrising your SQL. SQL injection is not your friend.

Comment: ok .I'm checking if the name is problem

Comment: @apomene, sql server is surprisingly forgiving when you use brackets, you can even use non-printable characters if you like (and watch the world burn).

Comment: If you have to use the word table  put it in brackets like this [table]   that way you can use reserved words and special characters I beleive, but still not a good practice and not very descriptive

Comment: @apomene you can create a table called `table`. `CREATE TABLE [TABLE]([COLUMN] int);` would work fine. You can even do REALLY silly things like `CREATE TABLE [dbo.The most **STUPID** [table]] name in the... World!] (ID int);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898/what-is-the-use-of-the-square-brackets-in-sql-statements

Comment: @HoneyBadger that reminds me of a question someone asked here a couple of months ago. It ended up that they had something like a `CHAR(0)` at the end or start of their object's name. /headdesk

Comment: Larnu, in your example, is "dbo." part of the table name? So I can select <dbname>.dbo.[dbo. blah blah blah]?

Comment: i have change the name .but same error

Comment: No, it's a different error...

Comment: You have changed the question, thereby invalidating the answer and these comments. You clearly get a new error, please do your research again and, if necessary ask a new question. And please change this question back to its original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your table is called `table` and that is a SQL reserved word, you have two choices:

1. Change your table name. This is the **only** option you should be considering but for completeness;
2. Quote the name of the table:

   ```
   insert into [table] values....
   ```

Comment: I would add that the OP MUST start using parameters in their queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @NavidAnjum You get *exactly* the same error? Hint: the answer is no, because you also changed the error message. I have answered your question, and you are now seeing a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

You do not list your column name on insert.  This means you are also attempting to insert your identity column as well.  Always list your column names

```
insert into NewName (firstname, lastname, username, email, password, contact)
values('" + first_Name.Text + "','" + last_Name.Text + "','" + user.Text + "','" + email.Text + "','" + password.Text + "','" + contact.Text + "')
```

Comment: After adding the column name it's showing error again .Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.

Comment: @NavidAnjum Output your `sql` before executing it, and see if there's syntax error or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I've done it .I was using "user" in table column which is not allowed .After changing the column name everything works.
This is the code

```
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        String sql = "insert into NewName  values('" + first_Name.Text + "','" + last_Name.Text + "','" + user.Text + "','" + email.Text + "','" + password.Text + "','" + contact.Text + "')";

     
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        // this line here is showing the error
        adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        command.Dispose();
        con.Close();
```