# Marketing Cloud - Query Studio: Field name cannot contain the character

Tags: sql

Some of our **Data Extention names** and the **fields** within those names have characters that makes it impossible for me to query.  Is there a way to escape these characters and allow me to query and get results?

**The error I get is:** "Error saving the Query field.Incorrect syntax near 'CampaignMember:'"

Query Example:

```
SELECT CampaignMember:Common:Email
FROM [Email Journey - 2021-03-22]
```

**Data Extension Name:** Email Journey - 2021-03-22

**Fields:**

- CampaignMember:Id
- CampaignMember:Common:Email
- MemberRecordType

Comment: put it between [ ] too?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by using square brackets and aliasing the table. Example:

```
SELECT t.[CampaignMember:Common:Email] 
FROM [Email Journey - 2021-03-22] t
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in my comment above you can put your column names between square brackets like this:

```
SELECT [CampaignMember:Common:Email]
FROM [Email Journey - 2021-03-22]
```

More info about using the square brackets:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52901/20126

Also worth mentioning you can also use Single or double quotation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms176027(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried that as well.

This is the query:
SELECT [CampaignMember:Common:Email]
FROM [Primary Email Journey - 2021-03-22]

I now get this error: 
Error saving the Query field.Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: and this error is happening on this query line or is there any SQL statements  you are running with this one?

Comment: Nope, this is the only query.   Could it be because "Primary" is a keyword in SQL?

Comment: What I know that the square bracket will work even if a keyword is used inside.